# IIS6 Setting Mapped to IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, iis-6

In IIS6 on the virtual directory tab there was a series of checkboxes which controlled access to a given folder (as pictured below):

[image: IIS6 Settings]

How do `Read` and `Write` checkboxes translate to the IIS 8.5 model?

Background:
I have a Classic ASP web application which requires write access to given folder path due to the fact that it uses the CPSHOST.DLL that I am attempting to migrate to IIS 8.5.  In IIS6, not only did I have to set appropriate NTFS permissions on the folder it was writing to, but I also had to check the `Write` box.  I have moved the application to IIS8.5, added the CPSHOST.DLL as an ISAPI extension and allowed it via the CGI and ISAPI restrictions.  I don't see anywhere that I can tell IIS that things are allowed to write to this folder.

CPSHOST.DLL is logging the following error in the Application Event Log:

```
User: testuser, Destionation URL: HTTPS://myserver/WebUploads/ The user does not have write access to the destination URL.
```

I have granted Read/Write NTFS access to the IIS Application Pool Identity and also the IUSR account (in IIS6, I had to grant the IUSER_MACHINENAME account write access and make sure the Write checkbox was selected in order CPSHOST.DLL to be able to write to the specified folder).

In IIS6 I get the same error if the `Write` checkbox is not selected.

Comment: Have you also given the SERVER\IIS_IUSRS group write permissions to the E:\uploads folder? (Right click on the virtual folder in IIS manager, Edit Permissions, Security tab, Edit.)

Comment: The IIS_IUSRS, application pool account and IUSR all have everything except for full control. This is only slightly driving me crazy.

Comment: I'd suggest then that it's a permissions issue with CPSHOST.DLL. You may need to add an "Allowed" entry under the "ISAPI and CGI restrictions" section. Can you check still if under IIS6 the CPSHOST.DLL had an entry under "Web Server Extensions"? This section is replaced by the "ISAPI and CGI restrictions" section.